# Compiled class in compiling file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a promblem with run-time compiled classes. I have something like this 2 classes:

first class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Program.Bullet {
  public class Class1{
    private int i;
    public Class1(int j){
      i=j;
    }
  }
}
```

and second class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Program.Bullet;
namespace Program.Object {
  public class Class2{    
    public Class2(){
      Class1 c1 = new Class1(5);
    }
  }
}
```

This two classes I would like to compile in run-time and use them in my project. So I have function to compile it (XmlNode has data about fullPath etc):

```
private ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder;
private List<string> isCompiled;

private void Compile(XmlNode compileingClasses) {
        foreach (XmlNode compileingClass in compileingClasses) {
            string fullPath = compileingClass.Attributes["path"].InnerText;
            string type = compileingClass.Attributes["name"].InnerText; ;
            if (!isCompiled.Contains(type)) {
                isCompiled.Add(type);
                var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile("../../File1/File2/" + fullPath);

                var comp = Compilation.Create("Test.dll"
                    , syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree }
                    , references: metadataRef
                    , options: comilationOption
                    );

                // Runtime compilation and check errors
                var result = comp.Emit(moduleBuilder);
                if (!result.Success) {
                    foreach (var d in result.Diagnostics) {
                        Console.WriteLine(d);
                    }
                    throw new XmlLoadException("Class not found " + fullPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to get the reference on Class1 to Class2?

Edit: Better question

Is it possible to create MetadataReference on compiled `Class1`?

Something like:

```
string fullName = bullet.Attributes["fullName"].InnerText;
var o = moduleBuilder.GetType(fullName);
metadataRef.Add(new MetadataFileReference(o.Assembly.Location));
```

This throw `NotSupportedException`

Comment: Both classes aren't in the solution and they are in separate files. My idea is to add reference on `moduleBuilder` to `metedateRef` but I don't know how.

Comment: Normally, it wouldn't make sense to add a reference to the same assembly. Not sure how it works with multiple complications in the same assembly. Can't you generate both classes in the same `Compilation` instead?

Comment: I re-design some functions to get all syntaxTrees into one compilation and it works. Thanks you, you save me some sleepless nights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reference the assembly which is currently being built and I don't think Roslyn can do that.

What you can do instead is to create a single `Compilation` from all your classes (probably having a separate `SyntaxTree` for each class). If you do that, you won't need any references.